# Checking/unchecking rule-visibility of layers at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, style

I've got several rule-based layers in my project (qgis 2.18.13).
Is it possible to check/uncheck the visibility of all rules (not the visibility of the layer itself) at once?
If yes - is it possible to do this on all layers of the project at once too?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. It would be nice and intuitive if selecting all of the rules and then clicking any of the checkboxes toggled all of the selected ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following to check or uncheck all rule-based style categories from all layers loaded in your project:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    renderer  = layer.rendererV2()
    if renderer.type() == 'RuleRenderer':
        ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())
        ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
        legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes(ltl)
        for ln in legendNodes:
            ln.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            #ln.setData(Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
```