# Catching signal when rule toggles (active/inactive) using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, rule-based

I would like to catch a signal when a rule within a rule based layer toggles visibility. How to permanently check this

```
layer.renderer().rootRule().children()[0].active()==True
```

the same way we can receive a signal when a node in the layer tree toggles visibility:

```
layer= iface.layerTreeView().currentNode()
layer.visibilityChanged.connect(dosomething)
```

The problem is I cannot catch the visibility change on a rule.

To add more context:

The layer "SM_GIS pds_electricity < 10000" is a copy of "PDS Electricité <2000" but with other scale ranges.

(I will hide it for the user but that's not the question here).

What I want:
if I set the rule "Prosumer" to visible in one layer , I want it to be set to visible in the same rule of the other layer.

[image]

A workaround is to make copies of the same layer and use single symbol and applying each rule to a new copy of the layer.

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! Can you give more context, the layer visibility rule for example, when it's append, etc. ?

Comment: Thanks! I have a layer with some rule based rendering. I did multiple copies of that layer to adapt symbology with scale. At the end I want to hide those copies and keep only one. So that when the user set visible layer(A).rule(1) the script detects it and toggle to visible the same rule in the other versions of the same layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signal you are searching is [QgsMapLayer.styleChanged](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html?highlight=qgsmaplayer#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.styleChanged).

And here a code below. I use partial to give as parameter the layer who has the rule checked/unchecked, this is for the case you connect multiple layers to the `updateRules` function.

- `activeRules` function create a dictionnary with label rules as keys and checkstate as values.
- `updateRules` function change rule visibility for all other mapLayers if the rule name is found.

```
from functools import partial

def activeRules(vectorLayer):
    vlar = dict()
    rend = vectorLayer.renderer()
    for lsi in rend.legendSymbolItems():
        chked = rend.legendSymbolItemChecked(lsi.ruleKey())
        vlar[lsi.label()] = (Qt.Unchecked, Qt.Checked)[chked]
    return vlar

def updateRules(vectorLayer):
    vlrules = activeRules(vectorLayer)
    # from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/261240/93097
    for ml in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        mlid = ml.id()
        renderer  = ml.renderer()
        if renderer.type() == 'RuleRenderer':
            if mlid != vectorLayer.id():
                ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(mlid)
                ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
                legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes(ltl)
                for ln in legendNodes:
                    nodname = ln.data(0)
                    if nodname in vlrules:
                        ln.setData(vlrules[nodname], Qt.CheckStateRole)

main_vl = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("PDS Electricité")[0]
main_vl.styleChanged.connect(partial(updateRules, main_vl))
```

Comment: It does work. 
I did the workaround with copies of the same layer and scale rules... it works also but far less elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Note that for faster code, if you have per layer unique rule names, you can add a `break` after the `ln.setData(`. The code I posted works with a layer that has multiple rules with the same name.